# PHP and access to a global object from everywhere

Tags: php

I have a global object, a "registry", it is a container with other important objects:

- Input object.
- Output object.
- DB object with connection.
- Logging object.
- Session object.

I need to have this global object in every place (object), where I process my request.

Like in my JBoss environment, where I have one Stateful Session Bean as a front controller, which directs the processing to a special Stateless Session Bean, I have one entry point, "facade.php".

In this facade.php, I create the global object and place the other objects (input object, ...) into it.

Then there is a large switch statement, where I redirect the request to special processing objects.

Is there a method, mechanism, to have access to this general object from the processing objects without handing it over as a parameter?

Comment: please write some static class ..set once and use many time as u want

Comment: Please could you add an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a variable available everywhere you can use a `$_SESSION` variable like so:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['registry'] = // Your data
```

Make sure to use the `session_start()` function whenever you want access to the session variables.

Comment: why to store in session it should forget once execution is complete

Comment: Because if the OP is jumping between separate files it makes sense to store it in this way, then use the `session_destroy()` function to remove once execution has completed.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do:

- put the Object into the Session. http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php (but this will survive "requests")
- Make the Object a singleton. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern (i recommend this, if its suitable for the situation. don't just use singletons to avoid passing parameters to classes/functions.)
- Mark the Object with the `global` keyword. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php